# Migrate from SQL Server 2014 Failover Cluster to 2019 Availability Group, rollback plan

Tags: sql-server, migration

we have a 2 node SQL Server 2014 failover cluster with 2 SQL Server instances and about 100 databases to be migrated to an availability Group 2019. What is the faster way to do that considering that we have one weekend for any instance? What's the best rollback strategy considering that restore from a recent version to a older one is not possible?
Any idea?

thanks

Comment: can you clarify if you are doing a side by side migration or whether you plan to re-use the servers you have ? (in place upgrade)

Comment: Different servers. We have two new server where two host AG 2019. The old servers will become test environment

Answer (score 0):

2 Massive questions

You haven't said anything about what is connecting to your databases.

For swapping over the databases log shipping will give you a much shorter cutover time than backup & restore.

If you can add a AOAG Listener with the name of the old server you will simplify updating all of the client connection strings (means the old server has to be powered down or renamed).

For rollback one generally has as thorough acceptance testing as possible - if that fails just power down the new server and power up the old one. Once clients are connecting and adding new data you have gone past the point of no return & know you have to fix any problems that occur on the new server.

Comment: Thank you Stephen in fact I thought the same. My biggest problem is the rollback. I tried something like Log shipping, mirroring but it doesn't work because of the version. I don't know all the applications that connect to the databases. We have about 100 databases and 50+ different application.

Comment: Does it need to be a big bang - why not run both servers for a couple of months and move a few databases at a time.
Very few shops that try and do a down version rollback - it's just too complicated.

You should make use of the db compatibility level and query store to help deal with plan regression

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/change-the-database-compatibility-mode-and-use-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Yes my intention is to have the same instance name and call the listeners with the same name of the old instances in this way the connection string remain the same. For rollback is a mess so I think I'll give up. Thank you again for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Too risky! You are doing 3 things at the same time:

1. Migration
2. Change from Failover Cluster to Availability Group
3. Upgrade from SQL Server 2014 to SQL Server 2019

Plus you said that you have 100 databases with 50+ different application hitting them. I don't want to be a psychologist but you are telling to me "What could possibly go wrong? I will probably get fired!". Of course you see there are too many variables and this can go wrong in so many ways.

If these databases are so critical my approach would be:

1. Use [Data Migration Assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-overview?view=sql-server-ver15) and run an audit that will tell you if there are any incompatibilities in the upgrade from 2014 to 2019.
2. Upgrade the 2 SQL Server instances from 2014 to 2019 and breath. After changing the Compatibility Level to 150 keep breathing for 1-2 weeks and see if all your 50+ application are still friends with your databases. (It should be alright, jumping from 2014 to 2019 is not too distant).
3. Now create an Always On Availability Group Asynchronous replica of one of your two instance.

Please comment if there's anything unclear.

Comment: Thank you Francesco for your reply, it's a good strategy but it takes a bit longer than I would like. Data Migration Assistant is a mandatory step , I absolutely agree. My idea is to migrate the smallest instance, just 20 DBs less important, and test it over weekend. If goes wrong I can switch back to the old cluster. My intention is to migrate the DBs on 2019 and keeping the compatibility level to 2014(120) and then increase it. I would like to keep the old instance as rollback.

Comment: Alright, this makes sense @Cris, keeping the compatibility to 120 is good. What about setting up Transactional Replication for test first and then for migration: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7QI1VjbS0YI&t=472s&ab_channel=RajasekharReddyBolla (The video is for Azure but you can do the same on your environment )

Comment: Exactly my intention is to use a node of 2014 as primary for a standalone 2019, or even AG 2019 I don't know if it works I'm still testing the architecture. At the right moment disconnect 2019 change the name of the old instance and IP and create a listener with the same name like the old instance and the same IP. At this point the application don't have even to change the connection string. If all good  proceed with changing the compatibility level to150. thanks again